# I have database backup and i am importing to another mysql server and it importing the database with the error of 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a database backup with 100+ tables(opencart databse) and I am importing that in another MySQL server and it importing only 23 tables with showing error  1061 error.

Static analysis:

2 errors were found during the analysis.

```
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "phpMyAdmin" at position 0)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "SQL" at position 11)
```

**SQL query:**

> phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 4.8.3 -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/ --
>   -- Host: localhost:3306 -- Generation Time: Dec 24, 2018 at 12:57 PM -- Server version: 10.2.19-MariaDB-cll-lve -- PHP Version: 7.2.7 SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"

**MySQL said: Documentation**

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
>   -- version 4.8.3
>
> ### -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
>
> -- Host: ' at line 1

Comment: Your file starts with the text "phpMyAdmin SQL Dump". That's simply not valid SQL code.

Comment: thanks for the response.so what should i do can you elaborate that briefly

Comment: I'm not fully sure of what kind of advice you want. You say you want to import a backup but you don't have a backup (or the one you have is damaged). So you need to get a working backup first. If your current backup tool cannot report whether backup fails, consider finding a better tool.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion

Comment: just use default phpmyadmin sql export tool. When you will have exported database, you can import it to another new one.